# How to find index in sorted array where occurs maximum value for the first time

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, max

How to find index in sorted array where occurs maximum value for the first time?

Let's take for example this array:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 200 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 ...201
```

where `201` is the maximum value.

Let's say that `201` occurs 200 times in this array. So the answer is that the index equals 200.

The native solution would be to iterate it as long as we get sth that `!=201`. But I guess that it is possible to find more effective solution. What algorithm do you suggest?

Comment: Why is this tagged as both [tag:java] and [tag:c++]?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to get the index of the array where 201 first appears or the total number of times 201 appears? Your statement `Let's say that 201 occurs 200 times in this array. So the answer is that the index equals 200.` makes this unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Binary search is `O(log n)` which is better than your naïve approach which has a complexity of `O(n)`. In c++, you'd use `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: And in Java, simple [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15603895/3216312) seems to work...

Comment: `std::distance(v.begin(), std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), v.back()));`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Binary search.

Native binary search will return any one occurrence of your key. Its "find " criteria is:

```
if(a[mid]==key)
    return mid;
```

Make a binary search function where your "find" criteria is:

```
if(a[mid]==key && a[mid-1]<key)
    return mid;
```

Also, if its a simple array, you can use a c++ standard template library (STL) function, `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard algorithm `std::lower_bound` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...    

size_t n = std::distance( std::begin( a ), 
                          std::lower_bound( std::begin( a ), 
                                            std::end( a ), 
                                            *std::prev( std::end( a ) ) ) );
```

where `a` is the name of a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate from the end of the array, not the beginning.  The first occurrence of the maximum value is likely to be closer to the end than the beginning.

```
for (int i = array.length; i >=0; i--) {
     do stuff
}
```

Comment: Bad solution. Say, my array is: a[100] = {1,2,2,2,2,2....2}. Then, ans is: index 1, and iterating from the end does 99 iterations.